Electric Potential Outside a Finite Length Cylinder
A similar question was asked here, but my question is more specific. Recently, after leaving an E&M exam I had some nagging doubts about one of the questions. The problem is solving for the electric potential (i.e. Laplace equation $\nabla^2 \Phi = 0$) in the exterior of a finite cylinder of length $L$ and radius $b$ placed on the $x-y$ plane.
Subject to the following boundary conditions on the cylinder,
$$\Phi(\rho < b,\phi ,z = L) = \Phi(\rho < b,\phi ,z = 0) = 0 $$
$$\Phi(\rho = b,\phi ,0 < z < L) = V_0 \sin\frac{\pi z}{L} \sin\phi $$
Easy (and I think wrong) Answer:
Using separation of variables and the standard orthogonal functions we can quickly arrive at the answer,
$$ \Phi(\rho,\phi,z) = V_0 \sin\frac{\pi z}{L} \sin\phi \frac{K_1 \left(\frac{\pi}{L} \rho\right)}{K_1\left(\frac{\pi}{L} b\right)}$$
This is the answer I got while taking the exam, and the answer listed on the answer key. However, I am fairly sure that it cannot be correct.
It does not satisfy the decay conditions as $z \to \infty$
I am looking for two things:

Am I missing something obvious, or did the instructor simply make a mistake? I only really care for my understanding and not for my grade because I put down the "correct" answer (as listed on the answer key).

Is there an easy way to get to the correct answer using separation of variables? I know I could do it by finding the correct Green's function, but we would not have had enough time to solve for it on the exam.



There is an ad hoc solution to your specific problem: For $z\in[0,L]$ your solution holds, and then for $z\notin[0,L]$ the potential is just zero. This is possible because the boundaries $z=0$ and $z=L$ happen to be identically zero for all $\rho$ and $\phi$

If the given boundary conditions were not happening to be so simple, it could have been a LOT worse. After all, nobody has yet analytically solved for a cylindrical capacitor, though we do have numerical approximations.

@naturallyInconsistent I thought of that, but I don't think that solution is right either. Because there will be a discontinuity derivative $\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial z}$ at $z= 0$ and $z=L$ indicating a charge density. In mathematical terms, the Laplacian will not vanish at these points.

^^ This is for the solution where we take $\Phi$ to be indentically zero for $z \not{\in} [0,L]$

Hmm, yes, you are correct. I'll have to think more

Let me tweak the notations slightly. In the following, I will set $V_0 = b=1$ and assume the cylinder is in $z\in(-L/2,L/2)$. Your lateral boundary condition is:
$$
\Phi = \sin\phi\cos(\pi z/L)
$$
Your method works to find the field inside the cylinder:
$$
\Phi(\rho,\phi,z) = \cos\frac{\pi z}{L} \sin\phi \frac{I_1 \left(\frac{\pi}{L} \rho\right)}{I_1\left(\frac{\pi}{L}\right)}
$$
However, assuming there are no charges outside, your solution:
$$
\Phi(\rho,\phi,z) = \cos\frac{\pi z}{L} \sin\phi \frac{K_1 \left(\frac{\pi}{L} \rho\right)}{K_1\left(\frac{\pi}{L}\right)}
$$
is wrong. Indeed, the $z$ axis has sinusoidal charge density, even outside the cylinder. This is the correct solution if you imagine that the planes $|z|=L/2$ are conducting and grounded (i.e. lift the condition $\rho<1$ in your first equation), in which case, the field beyond $(-L/2,L/2)$ are just images.
The spherical analogy would be the dipole field:
$$
\Phi(r=1,\theta,\phi) = \sin\theta\sin\phi
$$
for which you can easily solve inside and outside:
$$
\Phi(r,\theta,\phi) =\begin{cases}
r\sin\theta\sin\phi \\
r^{-2}\sin\theta\sin\phi
\end{cases}
$$
Essentially, separation of variables in cylindrical coordinates does not work because you need to "propagate" the solution radially like in spherical coordinates. In fact, this gives a method of finding the solution. Expanding:
$$
\Phi = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \Phi_k r^{-2k} P_{2k-1}^1(\cos\theta) \sin\phi
$$
you will then need to solve for $\Phi_k$ given the boundary conditions:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \Phi_k \cos^{2k}\theta P_{2k-1}^1(\cos\theta) &= 0 & \theta&\in(0,\arctan(2/L)) \\
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \Phi_k \sin^{2k}\theta P_{2k-1}^1(\cos\theta) &= \cos(\pi\cot\theta/L) & \theta&\in(\arctan(2/L),\pi/2)
\end{align}
$$
The final result will not be very pretty.
Alternatively, you can solve it using Green's functions. You still have double integrals to compute though.

Where is the expansion for $\Phi$ coming from? Shouldn't it be in terms of the spherical harmonics $Y_{l1}$? Something like,
$$ \Phi = \sum_{l} \Phi_l r^{-(l+1)} \frac{Y_{l1}(\theta,\phi) - Y^*_{l1}(\theta,\phi)}{2i} $$

Yes, that’s what I did. $\Im Y_l^1\propto \sin^l\theta \sin\phi$. Plus, thanks to reflection symmetry by the xy plane, you only need to keep odd $l$

Where is the identity, $ Y^1_l \propto \sin^l \theta e^{i \phi}$ coming from? I haven't seen it before and it doesn't match explicit expressions I have seen before e.g. $Y^1_3 \propto \sin \theta (5 \cos^2 \theta  -1) e^{i\phi}$. I don't see how this simplifies. If you have a reference I would be very grateful!

Yes you are absolutely right, I messed up the expressions (was using $P_l^l$ instead of $P_l^1$). The problem is pretty hard. I think it might be doable analytically without the azimutal dependence while being already instructive.
